# Concatenating in VBA within Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to accomplish something apparently simple but not for me. I’m new to all this and I would like to see if I can get any far with this first project. Basically I have, say 3 text boxes with a string in it (name) and a button next to them.  Then there is another text box which will hold all 3 names so that I could copy as one string into clipboard. Many tutorials out there refer to concatenating the strings however I’m still unable to find a decent answer. To be fully honest I am trying to achieve this task in VBA from within Excel 2010. So, my 3 names are actually in 3 different cells… Next to each of them I have a button with a macro attached (but vb will also be good for me) that will add the name into another cell. The buttons works ok but my problem is that I can’t get them to concatenate in Excel. Every button just overwrites what’s was there before. Any help? Suggestion? Tips? Mind you I can only be able to follow if the answer is simple and well explained as I am new to all of this. Thank you.

Comment: Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If you had 3 strings in A1, B1 and C1, you could get the concatenated string in D1 by putting in the formula `=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1)' in the cell D1. If you want to do it in VBA,

```
Public Sub MyConcatenation()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        .Cells(1, 4).Value = .Cells(1, 1).Value & .Cells(1, 2).Value & .Cells(1, 3).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

**If you won't take offense:** You need to pick up an introductory book or website to learn VBA (it is not VB or VB.Net). It will be a long, uphill struggle to learn it through asking questions on forums.